# VBA: Couldn't find names of textboxes created by control.add loop

Tags: vba, controls

I created textboxes with control.add loop but I couldn't change their values. I want their names tb1, tb2...

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For i = 1 To 10
    Dim cCntrl As Control
        Set cCntrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.textbox.1", "tb" & i)
   Next
   tb4 = "b"
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the controls via name as the compiler doesn't know about these names. Instead, you can assign the controls to an array. Probably you want to access the controls not only at Initializing, so declare it as global.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ctrlArr(1 To 10) As Control, i As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set ctrlArr(i) = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.textbox.1", "tb" & i)
        ctrlArr(i).Top = i * 20
    Next
    ctrlArr(4).value = "b"

End Sub
```